# Ruby - Problem with HTTP Post

Tags: ruby, http, post, http-post

this is my code:

```
   @data = "somedata\r\nsomadata\r\nsomadata\r\n"
   uri = URI.parse(my_url)
   http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
   resp, body = http.post(uri.path, @data)
```

When I try to run this, I get a 'sysread' error, saying that the end of file was reached (EOFError). 
Note that if I remove the \r of @data, the error doesn't occur, but I really need it.

I'm using Ruby 1.8.7, but a similar problem accurred with 1.9.2.

I am trying to convert a PHP class to Ruby, Here is the PHP code:

```
$req = 'somedata\r\nsomadata\r\nsomadata\r\n';
$r = new HttpRequest($url, HttpRequest::METH_POST);
$r->addRawPostData($req);
$resp = $r->send()->getBody();
```

Thanks!

Comment: I saw someone suggesting this: https://github.com/jnunemaker/httparty

Comment: It's working on PHP with this url: http://192.168.1.251/odbc/empresas.template

Comment: Maybe you should try to add http://

Comment: I tried with and without http, dont't think that's the problem. The URL is exactly the same used in PHP.

Comment: I tried the httparty gem, but it shows the same error.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use newlines in Http Post! If you are developing a web application you can use the standard br tag. What are you trying to make?

Comment: Well, I am converting a PHP class to Ruby, will edit the question with the code

Answer (score 0):

This is a shot in the dark but the default ContentType for net/http post is "x-www-form-urlencoded". Try setting the ContentType in the header to "text/plain". Take a look at the [net/http docs](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/classes/Net/HTTP.html#M001391) for how to set the header.

Answer (score 0):

Slightly late answer but I hope it helps.

Your code works with ruby 2.5.0p0 so possibly the error was caused by ruby standard library and got fixed meanwhile.

I tried with local sinatra server (`ruby simple-server.rb`):

```
require 'sinatra'

post '/*' do
  puts "I got #{params}"
end
```

And your code (`ruby example.rb`):

```
require 'uri'
require 'net/http'
my_url = "http://localhost:4567/"
@data = "somedata\r\nsomadata\r\nsomadata\r\n"
uri = URI.parse(my_url)
http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
resp, body = http.post(uri.path, @data)
```